# yaml marshal kubernetes ResourceRequirements

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm trying to marshal resources from a kubernetes CRDs I made,
in this exercise I created my struct then I want to marshal it but with `yaml.Marshal(my_struct)`
I get something like that:

```
limits:
  cpu:
    format: DecimalSI
  memory:
    format: BinarySI
requests:
  cpu:
    format: DecimalSI
  memory:
    format: BinarySI
```

The type I'm trying to marshal is https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api@v0.23.0/core/v1?utm_source=gopls#ResourceList
I want to get the values `cpu: "250m"` and not the `cpu.format: DecimalSI`

thanks

---

EDIT:
It seems that the `resourcesList` doesn't have everything it should for yaml marshal (it works for json) I was using the wrong package
`gopkg.in/yaml.v3` instead of this one  `sigs.k8s.io/yaml` which is a "A wrapper around go-yaml designed to enable a better way of handling YAML when marshaling to and from structs."

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the code that creates the structure?  That type is just a `map[ResourceName]resource.Quantity` and in isolation that output is surprising, but without seeing the code it's hard to explain why you'd get that.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze for your answer, I request the struct with the kubernetes client (I'm doing a controller, then try to marshal a part of the CRD with the `yaml.Marshal` function). I found the solution and will edit my question